# CGROUP, No encuentro cpu.weight

Tags: linux, docker

no encuentro cpu.weight, solo tengo `cpu.pressure` y `cpu.stat` y sin el weight no funciona mi minikube sobre docker. Como fuedo configurarlo?

Arch Linux
Linux familia-malpica 5.17.1-249-tkg-pds #1 TKG SMP PREEMPT Mon, 28 Mar 2022 17:28:31 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 3):

El problema es la version del kernel (`linux-tkg-pds`), la version que tengo es:

```
$ pacman -Qi linux-tkg-pds
Nombre                    : linux-tkg-pds
Versión                   : 5.17.1-249
...
```

Instale el paquete `linux` y con eso ya se arreglo:

```
$ pacman -Qi linux
Nombre                    : linux
Versión                   : 5.17.1.arch1-1
...
```